# navigator.app.exitApp() minimizes instead of exiting

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using cordova 5.3.3 and compiling for Android. navigator.app.exitApp() minimizes/sends to the background the app instead of quiting it. How do I close/quit the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to fully quit, but that is not normal operations.

You need to add the follow to your AndroidManifest.xml

[KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) scroll down till you find it.

It links to:

[public void killBackgroundProcesses (String packageName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses%28java.lang.String%29)

I QUOTE:

> Have the system immediately kill all background processes associated with the given package. This is the same as the kernel killing those processes to reclaim memory; the system will take care of restarting these processes in the future as needed.
>
> You must hold the permission KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES to be able to call this method.

Comment: thanks, do you know if adding this permission is enough to kill the process while using navigator.app.exitApp() ? Or any other JS function?

Comment: To be clear, adding the permission KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES is not enough to kill the process; you need to also call the function. The function you need to call is a Java library call. To make the call, you need a plugin; which you can find [in the repository](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/) or [make your self](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. In Android developer can not terminate the application. It is managed by Android itself. You can only manage the lifecycle of the app (pause, resume etc.).